# Preventing webgl glsl automatically inlining functions?

Tags: glsl, webgl, inlining

In my GLSL code, I have large functions being called multiple times.

As an example, inside my perlin noise function I run a hash function many times.

```
float perlinNoise (...) {
    ...
    float x0y0z0 = pcgUnit3(seedminX,seedminY,seedminZ);
    float x0y0z1 = pcgUnit3(seedminX,seedminY,seedmaxZ);
    float x0y1z0 = pcgUnit3(seedminX,seedmaxY,seedminZ);
    float x0y1z1 = pcgUnit3(seedminX,seedmaxY,seedmaxZ);
    float x1y0z0 = pcgUnit3(seedmaxX,seedminY,seedminZ);
    float x1y0z1 = pcgUnit3(seedmaxX,seedminY,seedmaxZ);
    float x1y1z0 = pcgUnit3(seedmaxX,seedmaxY,seedminZ);
    float x1y1z1 = pcgUnit3(seedmaxX,seedmaxY,seedmaxZ);
    ...
}
```

In my procedural generation algorithm, I call the perlin noise function multiple times.

I notice that for every time I add a call to the perlin noise function, the compile time for the shaders takes longer. I think the problem is that glsl inlines the function calls, and thereby the shader code becomes very large.

Am I correct about the inlining, and if so, how do I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 1):

On page 13 of the [GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf) it is described, how to set pragma derectives

- #pragma optimize(off)
- #pragma debug(on)

That would be the "inlining" case. "Am I correct about the inlining ..". For my knowlenge, no. Also not quite sure what is happening in the background. On Windows it gets transpiled to [ANGEL](https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle/+/master/README.md), maybe have a look at the source could help.

In general: try to lower the precession, consider that three digits 1.000 could be "nice" enough. Floats can only store 5 -6 digits anyway. Avoid branching. That should be the First Aid Kid.

Some debugger tools out in the wild (please make your own research)

- http://glsl-debugger.github.io/
- http://shader-playground.timjones.io/

Optimizer

- https://zz85.github.io/glsl-optimizer/

Comment: "#pragma allows **implementation dependent** compiler control." These pragma's might work but they don't actually have to do anything.